# Merge two arrays based on key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

UPDATED after trying the below suggestion it now gives the correct affect but enters it to many times.

Hi I have the following code what this does is creates two arrays then blend them into one:

$list_claimed_users = get_users('meta_key=claimed');

```
foreach ( $list_claimed_users  as $list_claimed_user ) {
   $a = get_user_meta($list_claimed_user->ID , "claimed");
   $nicknames[] = get_user_meta($list_claimed_user->ID , "nickname");
   $unserialized[] = unserialize($a[0]);

   foreach($unserialized as $key => &$metadata) array_push($metadata, $nicknames[$key]);

}
$claimed_array[] = $unserialized;

print_r($claimed_array);
```

BUt it now loops and adds the $a data in an extra time for each loop

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 31.08.2016
                    [1] => prize8
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test5
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test5
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test5
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test5
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 31.07.2017
                    [1] => prize7
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test6
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test6
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test6
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 31.08.2017
                    [1] => prize5
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test7
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test7
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 21.08.2017
                    [1] => prize6
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test8
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Could anyone please advise the best way to merge the two if if there is a simplier way to achieve this when creating the arrays originally.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: There is an array_merge method in PHP made for this kind of stuff. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving the nicknames and the meta-data, but before adding result to `$claimed_array`, you can do:

```
foreach($a as $key => &$metadata) array_push($metadata, $nicknames[$key]);
```

Then just add `$a` to the `$claimed_array`:

```
$claimed_array[] = $a;
```

Comment: Hey I did the following as mentioned

And get the following error: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array but as not metnioned in the post above when i get the claimed meta its serialized so i was unserializing it ... ill alter code above to show